# Can I use a front shifter designed for 3x10 speed setups on a 3x7 bike?

Tags: shifter, compatibility

There are front shifters marketed for 2x10 or 3x10 speed setups.

Why should they be only used in combination with a 10 speed rear shifter? Do they have any relevant influence on the rear sprockets, like different gap sizes?

I would like to purchase a 2x10 or 3x10 front shifter and use it on my 3x7 bike, given there are no problems with this combination.

Comment: Just to clarify: it seems like you have a 7s shifter, rear derailleur, and freewheel/cassette. You're asking if you can use a 10s *front* shifter, perhaps to replace a broken front shifter. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea.

Answer (score 4):

There will be a cosmetic difference—I'm sure the design of the front shifter will be different from that of the rear shifter. It's up to you to decide whether that matters.

A 10-speed chain is narrower than a 7-speed chain, and the cage of a 10-speed front derailleur is slightly narrower as well. I don't think this means that the cable pull for a 10-speed shifter is different (this is well-documented for rear derailleurs, not so for front). If the cable pull is different, you might have trouble shifting across all three sprockets.

Comment: May I suggest that OP hunts down some NOS.